# How to aggregate unique combinations and reorder them in a specifiy way?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have this dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CLASS': ['A', 'B', 'A'],
 'MEMBERS': ['foo & bar', 'bar & luz', 'baz']})

print(df)
#   CLASS    MEMBERS
# 0     A  foo & bar
# 1     B  bar & luz
# 2     A        baz
```

First, I want to group on the column `CLASS` and combine the unique values of the column `MEMBERS`. And secondly, I need the unique combinations to be in a specific order : `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'luz']`.

I was able to do the first one :

```
df.groupby('CLASS')['MEMBERS'].agg(lambda s: " & ".join(set(' & '.join(s).split(' & '))))

# CLASS
# A    foo & baz & bar
# B          luz & bar
# Name: MEMBERS, dtype: object
```

Can you guys show me how to achieve the ordering ?

My expected output is this :

```
# CLASS
# A    foo & bar & baz
# B          bar & luz
# Name: MEMBERS, dtype: object
```

Comment: Are these four values (`foo` .. `luz`) the only ones you will ever see? If not, what is the order of other elements? Is it to be induced from the partial ordering of those seen in `df`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with a custom dictionary:

```
order = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'luz']

mapper = {k: i for i,k in enumerate(order)}
# {'foo': 0, 'bar': 1, 'baz': 2, 'luz': 3}

out = (df.groupby('CLASS')['MEMBERS']
         .agg(lambda s: " & ".join(sorted(set(' & '.join(s).split(' & ')),
                                          key=mapper.get)))
      )
```

Output:

```
CLASS
A    foo & bar & baz
B          bar & luz
Name: MEMBERS, dtype: object
```

Alternative with a function and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from itertools import chain

def cust_join(s, order):
    mapper = {k: i for i,k in enumerate(order)}
    return ' & '.join(sorted(set(chain.from_iterable(x.split(' & ') for x in s)),
                             key=mapper.get
                            ))

out = (df.groupby('CLASS')['MEMBERS']
         .agg(cust_join, order=['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'luz'])
      )
```

Comment: I liked both solutions and I learned about the key. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by using the categorical dtype with `ordered = True`

```
cat_dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories= ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'luz'], ordered=True)
m = 'MEMBERS'
df.assign(MEMBERS = df[m].str.split(' & ')).explode(m).astype({m:cat_dtype}).sort_values(m).groupby('CLASS')[m].agg(' & '.join)
```

Output:

```
CLASS
A    foo & bar & baz
B          bar & luz
Name: MEMBERS, dtype: object
```